# Updated Merge Intervals Question #56 on Leetcode (Specifically in C)

Tags: c, pointers

The Leetcode question #56 "Merge Intervals" was updated in April 2019 and now takes an input/output parameter int** returnColumnSizes. Why is the returned column size even a double pointer when a single pointer/array would do just fine (all the lengths of the returned arrays should be 2, so there would be *returnSize number of 2s). This double pointer parameter is causing heap-buffer-overflows, preventing my program from running to completion.

If my returned array of arrays is only of size 1, and I do what's shown in the code at the bottom, it passes without problems. Once I increase the number of arrays (and the rows of returnColumnSizes) I get the error pasted below.

```
returnColumnSizes[0] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
returnColumnSizes[0][0] = 2;

/* Below code causes overflow

  for (int i = 0; i < *returnSize; i++)
  {
    returnColumnSizes[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    returnColumnSizes[i][0] = 2;
  }

*/

=================================================================
==30==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x6020000000b8 at pc 0x000000405644 bp 0x7ffc16dbf5c0 sp 0x7ffc16dbf5b8
READ of size 4 at 0x6020000000b8 thread T0
    #3 0x7f1287f2e2e0 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x202e0)

0x6020000000b8 is located 0 bytes to the right of 8-byte region [0x6020000000b0,0x6020000000b8)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f12893b82b0 in malloc (/usr/local/lib64/libasan.so.5+0xe82b0)
    #3 0x7f1287f2e2e0 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x202e0)

Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff8000: fa fa 00 00 fa fa 00 fa fa fa 00 fa fa fa 00 fa
=>0x0c047fff8010: fa fa 00 fa fa fa 00[fa]fa fa 04 fa fa fa fd fa
  0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fd fa fa fd fd fa fa fd fa
  0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fd fd fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8060: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
==30==ABORTING
```

Answer (score 0):

There maybe some factors that has a certain influence on the situation:
1. The allocation problem: You're saying that whenever you try to get to the other objects in the array, they are unreachable. That may occur in a situation where there wasn't allocated more than one object in the array.
2. A compiler problem which you can't do anything about it but it mostly unlikely to happen.

So let's go with the first option.